# Why do I receive _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) while P/Invoking from C# to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, parallel-processing

I have a simple method, which is supposed to blur the image using native code:

```cs
internal override void Apply(BitmapBuffer framebuffer, 
    BitmapBuffer backBuffer, 
    BitmapBuffer frontBuffer, 
    BitmapBufferRepository repository)
{
    var data = framebuffer.Bitmap.LockBits(
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, framebuffer.Bitmap.Width, framebuffer.Bitmap.Height), 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    ImageProcessing.GaussianBlur(data.Scan0, 
        data.Stride, 
        data.Width, 
        data.Height, 
        Radius);

    framebuffer.Bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

The GaussianBlur method is defined as following:

```cs
[DllImport("Animator.Engine.Native.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GaussianBlur(IntPtr bitmapData,
    int stride,
    int width,
    int height,
    int radius);
```

And in the C++:

```cpp
extern "C" void __cdecl GaussianBlur(unsigned char* bitmapData,
    int stride,
    int width,
    int height,
    int radius)
{
    // Gaussian kernel

    int diameter = 2 * radius + 1;
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> kernel = generateGaussKernel(diameter);

    // Blur

    auto copy = std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]>(new unsigned char[height * stride]);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        memcpy(copy.get() + y * stride, bitmapData + y * stride, width * BYTES_PER_PIXEL);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            FloatColor sum;
            float weight = 0.0f;
            int count = 0;

            int xStart = x - radius;
            int xEnd = x + radius;
            int yStart = y - radius;
            int yEnd = y + radius;

            for (int x1 = xStart; x1 <= xEnd; x1++)
                for (int y1 = yStart; y1 <= yEnd; y1++)
                {
                    // Find weight

                    int kernelX = x1 - xStart;
                    int kernelY = y1 - yStart;
                    float kernelValue = kernel[kernelY * diameter + kernelX];

                    // Premultiply alpha

                    FloatColor color;
                    if (x1 >= 0 && x1 < width && y1 >= 0 && y1 < height)
                        color = getFloatColor(copy.get(), stride, x1, y1);
                    else
                        color = FloatColor(0);

                    sum.R += (float)(color.R * color.A) * kernelValue;
                    sum.G += (float)(color.G * color.A) * kernelValue;
                    sum.B += (float)(color.B * color.A) * kernelValue;
                    sum.A += color.A * kernelValue;

                    weight += kernelValue;
                    count++;
                }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                FloatColor result;
                result.A = sum.A / weight;

                if (result.A > 0)
                {
                    result.R = ((sum.R / weight) / result.A);
                    result.G = ((sum.G / weight) / result.A);
                    result.B = ((sum.B / weight) / result.A);
                }

                setFloatColor(bitmapData, stride, x, y, result);
            }
        }
}
```

When my application is running in multithreaded environment (`Parallel.For`), attempt to call `GaussianBlur` causes a "Debug Assertion Failed" error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...nimator\Animator\bin\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows7.0\Animator.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 904

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Przerwij   Ponów próbę   Ignoruj   
---------------------------
```

It turns out that the assertion fails before the P/Invoke is actually done (breakpoint on 1st line in the native function never hits).

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** I've just checked that the assertion failure happens (sometimes) when *the second* thread tries to call the function.

By the way, all functions in my C++ code are implemented thread-safely, in particular none of them uses any outside resources except ones passed by parameters.

Comment: c++ code is never safe unless the c++ is managed.  Managed c# code add protection to the code and only allows pointer to access memory that is protected.  The micro contains Selectors which specifies the memory areas program is allowed to access.  When c# code attempts to access an invalid location an exception will occur instead of getting a Blue Screen.  Using UNSAVE in c# bypasses the exception handler and you then will allow Blue Screens.  You should be using Marshal methods to access the dllimport structure which then protects from getting out of memory exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure your calculations are correct for the loops? Have you considered using a ready-made library for this, rather than implementing it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I lied about the functions being implemented thread-safely. Both the functions which caused issues used a function "generateGaussKernel", which was not thread-safe. I fixed it in the following way:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<float[]> generateGaussKernel(int diameter)
{
    // *** HERE ***
    EnterCriticalSection(&gaussKernelCriticalSection);

    while (gaussKernels.size() <= diameter)
        gaussKernels.push_back(std::shared_ptr<float[]>(nullptr));

    if (gaussKernels[diameter].get() == nullptr)
    {
        float sigma = diameter / 4.0f;
        std::shared_ptr<float[]> kernel(new float[diameter * diameter]);
        int mean = diameter / 2;
        float sum = 0.0; // For accumulating the kernel values
        for (int x = 0; x < diameter; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < diameter; ++y) {
                kernel[y * diameter + x] = (float)(exp(-0.5 * (pow((x - mean) / sigma, 2.0) + pow((y - mean) / sigma, 2.0))) / (2 * M_PI * sigma * sigma));

                // Accumulate the kernel values
                sum += kernel[y * diameter + x];
            }

        // Normalize the kernel
        for (int x = 0; x < diameter; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < diameter; ++y)
                kernel[y * diameter + x] /= sum;

        gaussKernels[diameter] = std::shared_ptr<float[]>(kernel);
    }

    // *** AND HERE ***
    LeaveCriticalSection(&gaussKernelCriticalSection);

    return gaussKernels[diameter];
}
```

Obviously with additional calls to `InitializeCriticalSection()` and `DeleteCriticalSection()`.

Now the error has gone away.